# Not all rows getting loaded by using the fastload utility in Teradata from CSV file to a table from Teradata SQL assistant?

Tags: sql, database, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I am practicing to use Fastload/ Multiload utility in teradata to load a **sample** Credit card data which has around 1500000 records. The data get loaded unto 49k records and ends with an error "MaxErr49923".I have enclosed the load utility screenshot alongwith the error log file also the sample flatfile(csv) which I an trying to load. **Also the date field i.e issue date and expiry date always gets populated with null values**. Here is the empty table query which I have use.

```
DATABASE PRACTISE;
CREATE MULTISET TABLE CREDIT_CARD_RECORDS
(
Card_Type_Code VARCHAR(10),
Card_Type_Full_Name VARCHAR (30),
Issuing_Bank VARCHAR (30),
Card_Number BIGINT,
Card_Holders_Name VARCHAR(30),
CVV_CVV2 INT,
Issue_Date DATE FORMAT'DD-MM-YYYY',
Expiry_Date DATE FORMAT'DD-MM-YYYY',
Billing_Date INT,
Card_PIN INT,
Credit_Limit BIGINT
)
PRIMARY INDEX (Card_Holders_Name);
```

[image: Fastload tool in teradata sql assistant]
Error log file details

```
  .......46703,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4285413383016162,"Reita Dancy",834,"05/2017","05/2029",8,1210,170400
46783,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4195838028015311,"Gregorio Q Holmberg",979,"01/2017","01/2023",17,0505,96000
46807,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4872945616723659,"Wilson O Nichols",620,"10/2014","10/2026",7,2459,100800
46907,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4059953506470345,"Grayce D Truelove",151,"12/2017","12/2029",5,6090,107200
46983,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4243827234729130,"Hyman O Gonsalves",024,"05/2011","05/2029",10,9488,34100
47327,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4029223115017839,"Royce A Rencher",828,"09/2013","09/2024",15,3963,82000
47429,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4739490884291546,"Verda Z Tarbell",555,"09/2009","09/2023",27,3917,180900
47431,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4807314635184999,"Rose Nall",467,"12/2011","12/2025",17,8725,51900
47605,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4616137762819330,"Nikki H Ibarra",875,"11/2012","11/2023",3,0913,134100
47684,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4324426783341637,"Edna Ford",462,"12/2009","12/2022",14,0751,196400
47708,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4980702571860573,"Dale D Chapman",067,"09/2012","09/2020",20,9449,44800
47711,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4188345979583668,"Darren L Parkes",833,"08/2010","08/2018",4,9342,183500
48402,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4799378041834042,"Teresa P Delacruz",812,"05/2010","05/2020",13,4389,159600
48540,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4515502653866231,"Jeanette W Richmond",228,"11/2010","11/2011",26,5042,17400
49042,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4915603258686796,"Keith J Buckley",708,"10/2015","10/2030",15,3182,48100
49473,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4771127111386777,"Merrill Vrooman",350,"10/2014","10/2016",6,4282,107700
49762,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4242331801902791,"Herbert X Tate",971,"07/2007","07/2012",24,2696,13400
MaxErr49923,"VI","Visa","Cabela?s WFB",4703254908053528,"Jannette O Elsass",729,"03/2013","03/2022",19,8396,97400
RestartRowAt 50002
```

P.S I know I have used MULTISET table attribute the reason being I also needed to try with Multiload too.
The file I am trying to load is in following link [here](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZVx5SXZuVwX481dIg4Fyl9yuT0KChIRL4Wy).

Comment: The date format quite obviously doesn't match

Comment: Fixed the date issue but still the data loading stops at 49k th row.

Comment: Sure hope those are "fake" accounts. Character string delimiter in the log seems to be `"` but your dialog shows `'`. And for the dates it seems like you would want column format in the table definition to be `'mm/yyyy'` to match the data and de-select "Use System Locale" so the database does the conversion.

Comment: Did the same using  "  around 1400k records got loaded but with errors. Thanks for the fix. Date issue is solved. And also the accounts are fake and generated using algorithms which creates random data.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug. I found this bug in the most recent version of Teradataml package for python. They set the batch number wrong as `num_batches = int(df.shape[0]/batch_size)` (Teradataml version 17.0.0.4 fastload.py module, line 467). It should be  `num_batches = int(df.shape[0]/batch_size) + ((df.shape[0] % batch_size) > 0)` In python, `int` function will round down. So if your total row number is not a multiple of the batch size, the last batch will not be loaded. Idk how to let them know but this is quite obvious a bug. A quick fix is to make your chunk size or batch size to be big, so everything will be loaded in one batch. This is how I solve my problem now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "Idk how to let them know but this is quite obvious a bug." - I forwarded this information to the engineering team responsible for the teradataml library. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on total number of rows and batch size teradataml will add all remaining rows to the last batch and then load these. This means last batch will have less number of rows than batch size.
Please provide more information about the scenario you are trying. It will be good if you can provide the script / steps that you are executing. This will help the engineering team to reproduce the issue on their end and provide a fix.